# Adding a column/variable to PDO FetchAll row

Tags: php, mysql, database, object, pdo

I'm new to using PDO and have got a little bit stuck- is there a way I can add a row to the fetchAll array returned?

I want to use a value in the row and create a new value from it. I hope my example is clear enough-

```
 class.php
--------------------
class connect
{
//all PDO database connection functions here
}

class Display
{
   function cars($colour)
   {
   $crud = new crud();
   $crud->conn();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE colour=:colour";
   $stmt = $crud->db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':colour', $colour);
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows =  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 ****WHAT I WANT TO DO (see edit)*****
   foreach ($rows as $row) 
       {
          ADD A ROW CALLED 'newprice' that equals ($row['oldprice'] + 300 / 2)
       }


       $this->results = $rows;
    }
 }


 index.php
--------------------
//other html code...

$D = new Display;
$D->cars('1');
foreach($D->results as $row)
{
?>          

<div class="car">
    <h1>Car Name:</h2>
    <?=($row['model']);?>
    Old Price:
    <?=$row['price'];?>
    New Price:
    <?=($row['newprice']);?>    <- outputting the new row I created
 </div>
}?>
```

Can this be done or is there a different more efficient way of doing this?

**Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear with my example! I want to do a lot more than just mathematically alter the value for the new column- I want to preg_split/run it through another class etc!**

Best solution I've got so far is to create a new multidimensional array from the PDO provided array and then add/edit that array, like this:

```
     $new=array();
     $key_loop = 0;
     $row_loop = 0;

      foreach ( $rows as $val )
      {
       $keys = array_keys($val);
       foreach ($keys as $key)
         {                
         $new[$row_loop][$keys[$key_loop]] = $val[$keys[$key_loop]];      
         $new[$row_loop]['new_entry'] = 'this works';
         $key_loop++;
         }       
         $row_loop++; 
      $key_loop = 0;
      }
```

Comment: I think you mean "add a new *column*" to the returned rows.

Comment: Yes, the equivalent to that! I had a search and all I could find was stuff on binding columns which I don't think is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is cycling through the rows and sticking them in a new multidimensional array with the extra values I need- might not be the most elegant way but it works for me:

```
$new  = array();
$array_loop = 0;

$sql = "select old_price, item_id from car";

...

$stmt->execute();
$rows =  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $val)
{
    $new[$array_loop]['item_id']   = $val['item_id'];
    $new[$array_loop]['old_price'] = $val['old_price'];

    $newprice = $val['old_price'] + 300 / 2;
    $new[$array_loop]['new_price'] = $new_price;
    $array_loop++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, this code is a quick off the top of my head write-up (i.e. no guarantees) but I think something like this would work for you.

```
...

foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
   // Get old price
   $old_price = $row['oldprice'];

   // Do some stuff with old price
   $new_price = changeOldPrice($old_price);


   // Insert new price into same row, under the newprice column
   $sql = "UPDATE cars SET newprice=? WHERE id=?";
   $stmt = $crud->db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute( array(':newprice' => $new_price, ':id' => $row['id']) );
}

...

public function changeOldPrice($old_price)
{ 
    // Some random regular expression split
    $new_price = preg_split("[,]+", $old_price) 

    // Pass to random class
    $myClass = new MyClass;
    $new_price = $myClass->doSomethingCool($new_price);

    // Return
    return $new_price;
}
```

Now for the bad news, that is a *lot* of UPDATES being run and will severely degrade the performance. A solution is to use [transactions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm) to write all of them at one time.

**[EDIT]**
In response to your edit, see the updated code.

Comment: Wow that would be a lot of updates! It's definitely a way to do what I asked. First time trying PDO and thought it would be a lot more elegant than the standard PHP/MySQL connect. I've added an edit to my question, but thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this.

```
SELECT *, (oldprice +300 / 2) as newprice FROM cars WHERE colour=:colour
```

Comment: That would work! But I actually want to mess around with what would be the new price value some more than my example shows (feed it through different functions, compare it etc)

Comment: @penpen, that will add the column `$row['newprice']` just like you wanted and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: It would add a new row, but how can I manipulate that? I tried doing a foreach with "$row['newprice'] = 'TEST" but it wasn't changed it :\

Comment: @penpen, first you asked about fetching a new column in your result set. Now it sounds like you are actually asking about updating it. Two different questions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought they would be one and the same but they clearly aren't. I should have been more specific from the start, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if anybody has the same problem (over 600 views) here is the solution:

instead of cycling through the results with:

```
foreach($D->results as $row)
```

use

```
foreach($D->results as $key=>$row)
```

and manipulate $results with $key reference instead of $rows